# Matlab NN inputs & output maniuplation

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Assume I have this matrix, A :

```
A=[ 25     11   2010    10  23  75 
    30     11   2010    11  24  45 
    31     12   2010    19  24  44 
    31     12   2010    22  27  32 
    1      1    2011    14  27  27 
    2      12   2011    15  28  30 
    3      12   2011    16  24  42 ];
```

The first 5 columns represent the inputs of some measured parameters and the last column is the corresponding output. The number of rows is the number of taking these measurements.

I want to use Matlab Neural network GRNN with the function newgrnn ( or any other NN function ) to train the data up to the 5th row and test the remaining 2 rows inputs to evaluate their corresponding outputs.  I have tried many many times to do this but it always gives me error and the program did not run correctly.  I have looked to newgrnn help example but it is only for one input while I have in this example 5 inputs.

My question is how do we put the inputs and the output in the newgrnn function structure. Actually, I have very large matrix with 22 inputs and one output and the size of my matrix is 26352 by 23 but the above is only sample example.

Comment: You have tried many times already -- what exactly have you tried? Can you show us some code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't given any examples of what you've tried and what errors you get from your attempts, I'll have to give you a fairly generic answer.

Have a look at [the newgrnn help file](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/toolbox/nnet/ref/newgrnn.html).

> net = newgrnn(P,T,spread) takes three inputs,
>
> ```
> P         R-by-Q matrix of Q input vectors
> T         S-by-Q matrix of Q target class vectors
> spread    Spread of radial basis functions (default = 1.0)
> ```

So if your matrix `A` always has just the last column being the outputs (target class vectors) then the outputs (target class vectors) are `A[1:5,end]`, and the inputs are `A[1:5,1:(end-1)]`. These say "first 5 rows of `A`, and the last column", and "first 5 rows of `A`, and all but the last column" respectively.

Then (simply following the example in the `newgrnn` help file, you will have to tweak to your own particular `A`):

```
net = newgrnn( A[1:5,1:(end-1)], A[1:5,end] )
% predict new values
Y = sim(net, A[6:7,1:(end-1)])
```

I think you should also read the Matlab help file for [indexing arrays and matrices](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html).

Comment: Thanks. But I think the extracted matrices should be transposed to make the inputs and the output matrices have the same number of columns. If I run the above newgrnn code, it gives:              ??? Error using ==> newgrnn at 80              Inputs and Targets have different numbers of columns.

Comment: ah, you're right, `P` needs to be `R` rows `Q` columns, and `T` needs to be `S` rows `Q` columns. Transposing will get rid of that error, but I don't know enough about neural networks to tell you whether that's the correct thing to do intellectually. But since you are using 5 rows of `A` to predict the other 2, why don't you try and see if it gives you what you expect?